# Error with Breif , Brisk descriptor opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-descriptor

**I am facing a error while using BREIF descriptor in open cv.
The error is that BREIF is not able to give descriptor for all the key point. It give descriptor for less number of keypoint than expected.Error I am getting is following**.The error is only using breif descriptor.There is no error using SURF and SURF descriptor

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (masks[i].rows == queryDescriptorsCount && masks[i].cols == trainDescCollection[i].rows && masks[i].type() == CV_8UC1) in checkMasks, file /home/shashank/Desktop/opencv-2.4.5/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp, line 259
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/shashank/Desktop/opencv-2.4.5/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp:259: error: (-215) masks[i].rows == queryDescriptorsCount && masks[i].cols == trainDescCollection[i].rows && masks[i].type() == CV_8UC1 in function checkMasks

On further enquiry we get
No of keypoint in previous image 957
No of keypoint in next image 910
size of breif descriptor **32X880. It should be  32X957**
size of breif descriptor **32X847. It should be  32X910**
**mask [910 x 957]**

**The code is as follow**

```
     cv::Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector=new GridAdaptedFeatureDetector(new SurfAdjuster(),keypt,noofbucketinwidth,noofbucketinlength);//surf


 //cv::Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector=new GridAdaptedFeatureDetector(new FastAdjuster(10,true),keypt,noofbucketinwidth,noofbucketinlength); //FAST

     detector->detect(img,keypointimage);
    cout<<"noof keypoint "<<keypointimage.size()<<endl;


    //for descriptor
    Mat descriptor;
     Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractdetector=DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
     Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractdetector=DescriptorExtractor::create("BRIEF");   
        extractdetector->compute( img, detectedpoint, descriptor);    

    //for matching
    if(FAST_H_prev.empty())
            FAST_H_prev = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);

        std::vector<unsigned char> FAST_match_mask;

        if(!currentimagekeypoint.empty())
        {
            std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> test_kpts;
            warpKeypoints(FAST_H_prev.inv(), nextimagekeypoint, test_kpts);

           cv::Mat FAST_mask = windowedMatchingMask( test_kpts, currentimagekeypoint, 25, 25);
                matcher->match(Discriptorofnextimage,Discriptorofcurrentimage, FAST_matches, FAST_mask);
                      matches2points(currentimagekeypoint, nextimagekeypoint, FAST_matches, FAST_train_pts, FAST_query_pts);
            if(FAST_matches.size() > 5)
            {
                cv::Mat H = findHomography(FAST_train_pts, FAST_query_pts, RANSAC, 4, FAST_match_mask);
                if(countNonZero(Mat(FAST_match_mask)) > 15)
                    FAST_H_prev = H;
                else
                    FAST_H_prev = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);
                               drawMatchesRelative(currentimagekeypoint, nextimagekeypoint, FAST_matches, currentimage, FAST_match_mask);

            }
        }
    else
    {
        FAST_H_prev = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the OpenCV implementation, the Breif descriptors remove the keypoints too close from the borders.

```
//Remove keypoints very close to the border
KeyPointsFilter::runByImageBorder(keypoints, image.size(), PATCH_SIZE/2 + KERNEL_SIZE/2);
```

A solution could be to filter the Keypoints in your code and then exctract the descriptors.